# mapper_parsing_exception while updating a document in elastic search using javascript client

Tags: elasticsearch

I fetch a document from ES and then try to update it using js client:

Structure of document is as(partial):

> {
>
> _id = "2c3cb61e-fd2a-11e8-8ac1-0242ac110008",
>
> _index = "my_index",
>
> _source: {taskName: "Task_name",....}
>
> }

Code:

```
 hit._source.taskName = 'New_task_name';
 esClient.bulk({
 body: [
     { update: { _index: 'my_index', _type: 'default', _id: hit._id }},
     { doc: hit}
 ]
}, function (err, resp) {
 // ...
 console.log(err, resp);
});
```

But it gives error as:

> { "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",   "reason": "Field [_index] is
> a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index
> API request parameters." }

Does it mean I can't have _index as field name in my document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great job so far, you're almost there!! You only need to send what's in the `_source`, do it like this instead:

```
 hit._source.taskName = 'New_task_name';
 esClient.bulk({
 body: [
     { update: { _index: 'my_index', _type: 'default', _id: hit._id }},
     { doc: hit._source}                                               <-- change here
 ]
}, function (err, resp) {
 // ...
 console.log(err, resp);
});
```